# How to fix red error screen unsanitizedScriptURLString = (null) when running react-native in Xcode

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, create-react-native-app

I get this error when I run react-native in Xcode, IOS simulator. I am using code sample from [RNTester](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/RNTester). I am having a problem testing this code sample.

[image]